# SSIS - A package level connection (Connection A) has same {ID} in all packages. Where to configure it?

Tags: ssis, connection

I'm new to SSIS (but not similar ETL tools).

A previous dev left me a steaming pile.

Anyway I noticed there are a couple "project level" connections. Makes sense. Configure a connection that's re-used across say 30-40 packages in the project.

However, there is one connection that is not (project) prefixed. It's a package level connection, but every package has it, and it's the same {random-alpha-numeric-ID} in every package. I *know* it's the same connection --- in reality -- it's named the same thing.

Trouble is, I don't want to set this connection again, and again, and again, for 40 packages. I get the feeling there is a "configuration"? file in SSIS somewhere, where this connection is set dynamically. Still no idea why this wasn't made a project-level connection, but --- does any of this make sense what I'm saying? How do I configure this?

Comment: You'd like to right click inside `control flow` and click `package configurations`. Ideally, the approach used for package level deployment is, package configurations are set to sql-server type. ie, in your destination, there should be a `SSISConfigurations` table holding up connection details, package wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSIS Packages are XML at the end of the day. Its a bit of a hack & I'd backup the whole solution first.... BUT if it were me I would take a single package & then:

- "View code" & copy out the XML for the package
- Manually update the package connection in the GUI to use a new project connection
- "View code" & copy out the XML for the package again
- Compare the 2 XML files & find the block of code setting the new project connection
- Apply the same XML code block to every other package in the solution....

I can't think of an easier way - maybe someone smarter than me has some ideas?

Comment: Definitely the best idea I've heard yet --- I'm definitely an SSIS rookie and it's not as intuitive as other ETL tools, but I'll give that the old college try, thanks. I mean I'm 30 but ya know.